# Moving Ubuntu 18.04.1 OS from HDD to new SSD for faster boot

Tags: 18.04, disk-image

I want to move Ubuntu from my 2TB hard drive to a 512GB solid state drive to improve my boot speed. Ubuntu is the only OS I use.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Easiest is just do a new install, then  copy /home & use exported  list of installed apps to reinstall all your applications. Quicker than just about any other copy process. And if image copy, you cannot have HDD installed when rebooting, until you change UUIDs as duplicates are not allowed. I like to have an install on every drive anyway. Is system UEFI or BIOS, is Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode. You also cannot just copy a gpt partition, but  only the entire drive without major changes to GUIDs.